# Docker Desktop for Windows -- How to specify an executable entrypoint?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

What is the correct syntax for specifying an executable entrypoint? For instance, I build a project which produces an executable (e.g. "example.exe") which gets copied to the docker container under `C:\app`. I cannot seem to get the `Dockerfile` entrypoint correct, it always fails always relating to not being able to find the specified exe, the path being invalid, etc. The Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2-windowsservercore  
ARG source=.  
WORKDIR /app  
COPY $source .   
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/example.exe"]
```

I've tried numerous strings in the entrypoint:

- example.exe
- C:\\app\\example.exe
- /app/example.exe

none of these strings work so I'm confused on how to run that exe as the entrypoint.

Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding the use of "entrypoint" and I need to use something else like "run"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to use the ["shell"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) form:

> FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2-windowsservercore
>   ARG source=.
>   WORKDIR /app
>   COPY $source .
>   ENTRYPOINT "example.exe"